# Какой должен быть размер базы при дампе?

Tags: linux, postgresql, резервное-копирование

смотрю размер базы через pretty

```
postgres=# SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_database_size( 'soft' ) );
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 2524 MB
(1 row)
```

делаю дамп базы командой

```
pg_dump -x -O -U postgres -h localhost soft > db_soft.sql
```

смотрю сколько она весит с помощью `du sh *` получается 346 мб.
Команда `select pg_database_size('soft');` возвращает тоже 2,5 гб

Почему так получается? должен ли дамп базы весить столько же? Это нормальное поведение, если я начну восстанавливать данные, то все восстановится нормально?

Comment: дамп БД это sql-текст на ее создание. А БД реально на диске хранится совершенно в другом виде, а не в виде запросов которыми она создавалась и конечно размеры совершенно различны

Comment: Если я сделал дамп базы, потом изменил последовательность id `ALTER SEQUENCE bills_id_seq RESTART WITH 8532` (к примеру), понял что это неправильно и хочу вернуться обратно, то в таком случае дамп мне поможет?

Comment: дамп это просто текст. Посмотрите его в любом редакторе, найдите в нем ваш секвенс и думаю все вопросы пропадут сами собой. В нем же   наверняка будет `сreate sequenсe` со всеми необходимыми параметрами, включая стартовое значение

Comment: я имею ввиду восстановить из дампа, где секвенса еще нет. это сработает? ну или не брать секвенс, а например индекс я ненужный создал и хочу откатить к дампу без индекса.

Comment: Отката нет. Вы удаляете БД и создаете ее с нуля на то состояние которое было во время дампа и если индекса не было, откуда бы ему взяться в дампе ...

Comment: для Point In Time Recovery используйте pg_basebackup и сохраняйте WAL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это нормальная ситуация, если при работе с базой активно используется удаление. Команда `DELETE` не освобождает занимаемое место на диске.

Попробуйте выполнить команду [vacuumdb --full](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-vacuumdb.html) и проверить, сколько займёт на диске база после сжатия.

Comment: спасибо) есть какие-нибудь best practice для backup'а базы? одной команды pg_dump не слишком мало?

Comment: Я всегда пользовался ```pg_dump``` и пока всё проходило без особых проблем. Это рекомендуемое решение, насколько я знаю.